# Drives mounted via WSGI Apache sudo command not visible on host

Tags: apache, ubuntu, sudo, mount

On an Ubuntu 18.01 LFS system (my private home server, only accessible from my home LAN), I have created an Apache/WSGI/flask web application that mounts encrypted drives (via `cryptsetup luksOpen` and then `mount`) on web request. Password for cryptsetup is sent via HTTP POST, a python script (that calls itself via sudo and then calls `cryptsetup` and `mount` via subprocess.run) is entered in /etc/sudoers.d... without the need for a password, so everything runs fine with `sudo -u www-data ./starthepythonscript_that_mounts_stuff_via_sudo.py` without a password. I can see mounted drives and `cd` into them after calling this script as just mentioned.

However, this behavior seems to be different when the script is called from the same user "www-data", but from the Apache WSGI Ubuntu service. In this case, mounting seems to succeed, but the mounts are not visible on the system (neither when listing contents of the corresponding mounted folder, nor when typing `mount` - e.g. as root - on the system that runs Apache). They just don't show up - is there a kind of sandbox mechanism implemented for the Apache service on Ubuntu?

My goal is to mount the drives via the Apache/WSGI/flask/sudo script, but in a "normal" way such that users on the same machine can see this via `mount` or `cd` into it.

Any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I have found the answer on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398408/strange-behaviour-with-the-mount-namespace-of-apache2-on-raspbian) - the apache service is started with `PrivateTmp=true`, which creates a private mount kernel namespace. One option is to remove that flag or set it to false - another would be to keep the setting and (from the root namespace) use `nsenter -a -t APACHEPID bash` to start a bash that sees the mounts.